# JMeter -samples fail when just running with 2+ VU

Tags: jmeter

Here are my scripts:
go to webpage(record the token for login), 
login, 
got to webpage(record the token for logout)
log out,

When I run this thread with 1 VU, it works fine.
But when I run with 2+ VU, one of the user always failed with error="invalid token".

I checked the token which was passed correctly--means user1 has its token, and user2 has its token. I could not figure out why the test results fail at this stage. I added constant timer, throughput timer but nothing helped.
When I run with 6 VU, the results varies more--sometimes 3 VU are successful, sometimes only 1 is successful. I can't find the pattern. Could anyone please help me here? I know my pc is not a good loadrun server, but I am talking about only run 2-6 threads, why does it fail with such little threads?

Comment: What do you mean by "2+ VU", number of threads? What kind of error did you get? If you didn't done it already, try to add Debug PostProcessor and "View Results Tree" Listener to obtain full information.

Comment: 2+VU=2 threads.the error="invalid token"
1. the token is correctly passed since I compared the token that was generated (using regular expression extract) by homepage and passed to login page. I checked the results and see each user has its own token. that is why I am puzzled why on earth I got that "invalid token" error. I used debug postProcessor and see the token is passed correctly for each VU. Any other possibility?

Comment: exact error is this: {"errors":{"error:":["ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken"]}}

Answer (score 0):

First of all try adding a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to see if errors are session/cookie based.

If it won't solve your issue try recording your request several times, detect which tokens are being dynamic and get them by not recording but with a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Comment: I do have Http Cookie Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out--> the token should have "encoded" checked in the parameter place. I got answers from this link: http://ertw.com/blog/2010/06/29/load-testing-a-rails-app-and-the-authenticity_token/